# Automatic download file from restFul Api with Net5

Tags: c#, .net-5

I have a restFul api with Net5, in this api I have a controller where an array of bytes is obtained that corresponds to a file (pdf, png, jpg...) that must later be sent to the client and automatically downloaded in the browser, but when doing my tests from Swagger the only thing I get is:

[image: swagger]

As I see it is not working correctly since I do not see the byte array anywhere and I only see the names of the classes in swagger.

```
    [HttpGet("{IdFichero}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerFichero(int IdFichero)
    {
        DbResponseImageHub response = await _unitOfWork.MensajeRepository.ObtenerImagenMensajeRepository(IdFichero);

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(response.fichero);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
        result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "Document " + response.extension;

        switch (response.extension)
        {
            case "png":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/png");
                break;
            case "jpg":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/png";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpg");
                break;
            case "jpeg":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/jpeg");
                break;
            case "bmp":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("image/bmp");
                break;
            case "pdf":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                break;
            case "docx":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.documen");
                break;
            case "doc":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/msword");
                break;
            case "xlsx":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
                break;
            case "xls":
                HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/vnd.ms-excel");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return Ok(result);
    }
```

If I use the FileResult, it shows me the error "The non-callable FileResult member cannot be used as a method."

```
return FileResult(result);
```

If you could tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: dont return OK return FileResult

Comment: @OMANSAK Thanks, If I use the FileResult, it shows me the error "The non-callable FileResult member cannot be used as a method."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return `File` object from your controller. Below is a code example which is very close to what you are trying to do (The file object must contain the bytes array for your file)

```
    [HttpGet("{IdFichero}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ObtenerFichero(int IdFichero)
    {
        string localFilePath = "C:\\1639842533574.jpeg";
        string extension = "jpeg";
        var myBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(localFilePath);

        switch (extension)
        {
            case "jpg":
                return File(myBytes, "image/jpg");
            case "jpeg":
                return File(myBytes, "image/jpeg");
            default:
                return File(myBytes, "image/gif");
        }
    }
```